# React Native Navigation Structure

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

A tab bar with 5 tabs.

And each tab is a list of items, say  IndexScreen.
On click of the item, it moves to a new screen say SingleItemScreen
In this screen there will be a section for items which are related, on click it moves to same SingleItemScreen with different param data.

The same repeats to other tabs.

I am stuck in structuring the Navigation for a week. I could not figure it out.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Without code it's hard to help. It seems like you need global store (redux) to pass state across components.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you will be using `react-navigation`. If each tab is just a list of items, you will go just fine with `createBottomTabNavigator({
 screenOne,
 screenTwo,
 screenThree,
 screenFour,
 screenFive
})`.

You can read more on https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/bottom-tab-navigator.html